Vulkan data struct alignment for Spir-V
In my C++/Vulkan application, I am passing data to my shaders with structs using #pragma pack and this is kinda temperamental with alignment. For example, if I order it so there's a vec2 before vec4 for example the alignment won't match what the shader is expecting. Is there any library that I can use to put these into a tuple or something so that the alignment will match? Or am I best off just using my current approach? I really don't want to use separate uniform buffers for each piece of data. I'm kinda surprised glm doesn't have some kind of tuple type for this purpose.
my C++ code...
#pragma pack(push, 1)
    struct DataBuffer {
        glm::vec4 rgba;
        glm::vec2 origin;
        glm::vec2 output_dims;
        glm::vec2 scale;
    };
#pragma pack(pop)

My GLSL shader code...
layout(binding = 0) uniform t {
    vec4 rgba;
    vec2 origin;
    vec2 output_dims;
    vec2 scale;
};


Look up std140 and std430.  You decorate your glsl structs with one of these and pad your C structs to match.
